# Insert/ Updating php variables into database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i just want to ask one question. How to insert php variables into database .

The 2 variables i want to insert are namely $profitText and $closedb. I tried 2 methods but both to no avail. Please enlighten me !!

```
 $mysqli-> query(
     "UPDATE trade_history1 set close='{$closedb}' 
        WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);

$mysqli->query(
     "UPDATE trade_history1 set profitandloss='" . addslashes($profittext) . "' 
        WHERE `trade_id` = '" . addslashes($trade_id) . "'");

///////

$mysqli->query(
     "INSERT INTO `trade_history1` (
        user_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, 
                      offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit,dateclose,close,profitandloss)
          SELECT user_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, 
                 offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit, 'null','null','null'
           FROM `opentrades`
           WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);

    $mysqli->query("UPDATE trade_history1 
             set dateclose=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE trade_history1 
             set close='{$closedb}' WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE trade_history1 
             set profitandloss='" . addslashes($profittext) . "' 
             WHERE `trade_id` = '" . addslashes($trade_id) . "'");

    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `opentrades` WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

"to no avail" is not a very meaningful description of what happened. If the query was sent to the database and not successfully processed then the database would have given you an explicit error message saying why.

Further you should not use addslashes() to escape values you splice into queries. Using [parameter binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) with placeholders or [mysqli::real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (although an explicit cast to integer is also a reasonable approach for integer data types / an array lookup for enum values).

When debugging at the boundary between PHP and MySQL, it's a good idea to look and see exactly what SQL your code is sending to the database (while this is not visible at te PHP end using parameter binding, it is visible at the database end).

Also, you should ensure on your development environment that any errors detected by PHP are visible somewhere - maybe you don't have a database connection?

Fromt the information you've provided there's no way to tell why it's broken (the SQL *looks* OK)

Comment: There is a connection. Its only the 2 UPDATE involving the 2 variable that does not work , the one that works is only the time stamp . Which gets keyed into database.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use mysql, but use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info). Note the connection code which is essential.

Next, here is the right way to do it:

```
$sql = "UPDATE trade_history1 set close=?, profitandloss=? WHERE trade_id = ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($closedb,$profittext,$trade_id))
```

Answer (score -1):

try single quotes the sql and double quotes the php variable, though i am not sure if you want to insert the variable or want to insert the variable evaluation into the db

Comment: $mysqli-> query('UPDATE trade_history1 set close="{$closedb}" WHERE `trade_id` = ' . $trade_id); like this

Answer (score -1):

First you can change more than one column in a single query. So your first and last set of queries can become :-

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE trade_history1 
                          set close=?, profitandloss=? WHERE trade_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $closedb, addslashes($trade_id), $trade_id);

if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
   // error processing code
}
```

Similiarly with the last set of updates:-

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE trade_history1 
             SET dateclose=NOW(), close=?, profitandloss=?
             WHERE trade_id = ?";

$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $closedb, ddslashes($profittext), $trade_id);

if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
   // error processing code
}
```

And your create a history query:-

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
     "INSERT INTO trade_history1 (user_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, 
                              bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit,dateclose,
                              close,profitandloss)
      SELECT user_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, 
             offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit, NULL, NULL, NULL
       FROM opentrades
       WHERE trade_id = ?";

$stmt->bind_param('i', $trade_id);

if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
   // error processing code
}
```